# Find cells with data and use as index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading an excel file, but for this question purposes I will provide an example of what my dataframe looks like.
I have a `dataframe` like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Texas 1', '111', '222', '333'],
        ['Texas 1', '444', '555', '666'],
        ['Texas 2', '777','888','999']
    ])
df[2] = df[2].replace('222', '')


          0    1    2    3
a   Texas 1  111       333
b   Texas 1  444  555  666
c   Texas 2  777  888  999
```

And I want to be able to define a multiindex based on the values of the first row that are not blank.
So something like this:

```
      0     1    3
Texas 1   111  333 444  555  666
Texas 2   111  333 777  888  999
```

The problem is that the values in row `a` will not always be in the same column, so I need a way to find which columns have a value in the first row and use that column number as an index. So far, I read my excel file like so:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('excel.XLS', index_col=[1,11,24,37])
```

And I've been looking for a way to read the cells that are not `NaN` and are in `row a` and find their column number to store in a list and use that as for my `index_col=()`. But I can't figure out how. Any pointers in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: I just dont understand what you want

Comment: @Noobie I want to be able to save to a `list` the column number for each cell in `Row a` that is not `NaN`. This way I'll be able to specify which columns I want to use as a multiindex since the columns are not always gonna be the same

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you say "where is not NaN" but you `replace` with `''`.
I'll replace `''` with `np.nan` then `dropna`

```
df.iloc[0].replace('', np.nan).dropna().index

Int64Index([0, 1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

---

```
df[df.iloc[0].replace('', np.nan).dropna().index]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `df[df.iloc[0].replace('', np.nan).dropna().index]` is what I needed. I used the `df` that this created to get a `list` of columns that have values in the first row (or second because of header) and then I used that in `df1 = pd.read_excel('excel.XLS', index_col=[1,11,24,37])` to replace the `index_col` values. This worked

Comment: @rubito consider marking it as the answer if you feel that is appropriate.